# How to get ready a C++ project with OpenGL, Glut and Visual Studio 2008 in Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opengl, glut

As I had many problems setting Visual Studio 2008 for using OpenGL I will ask this question that can be useful to some people:

> Which are the steps to follow in order to use OpenGL with C++ in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822750/setting-up-opengl-with-c-and-visual-studio-2008

Comment: mmm, not really, there's no GLUT or Winodws 7 in the question and tags, and there's no good answer

Comment: You don't need GLUT, it's not a vital part of OpenGL. Of course if you want to compile some tutorial that uses GLUT you'll have to install it.

Comment: And what do you suggest instead of GLUT, just to give a try and see if I like it more?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all you need to have a video card and check that it works with OpenGL and the drivers are updated. I used the test in this [link](http://www.chw.net/foro/benchmarks-f44/110589-nuevo-test-opengl-para-gpu.html) to check it.

It is also important to check that Visual Studio 2008 is correctly installed and that the following path is created in your computer:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A

Now we can follow the installation steps:

1.- **Download GLUT** from https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut_downloads.php, unzip and copy the files as instructed below:

- **glut.h** to the folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include\gl\
- **glut32.lib** to the folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\
- **glut32.dll** to the folder  C:\Windows\System32\

2.- Create an empty C++ Win32 application:

- From File menu select New → Project (Ctrl+Shift+N).
- Select Win32 Project, enter a Name, and click OK.
- In the Wizard click Next, then check the box next to Empty Project,
  and click Finish.

3.- Add a new C++ source file:

- Under the Project menu select Add New Item (Ctrl+Shift+A).
- Select C++ File (.cpp), enter a Name, and click OK.

4.- **Link to the OpenGL libraries** (important step):

- Under the Project menu select **Project Properties** (Alt+F7) at the bottom.
- Select **Configuration Properties → Linker → Input** from the navigation panel on the left.
- Select **All Configurations** from the Configuration drop-down box at the top of the dialog. This ensures you are changing the settings for both the Debug and Release configurations.
- Type **“opengl32.lib glu32.lib glut32.lib”** in Additional Dependencies and click OK (the opengl32.lib and glu32.lib are already in the system, and glut32.lib will be after downloading GLUT).

5.- Download this [sample code](http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~cs229/guides/SampleGlut.cpp).

6.- It is also necessary to set the paths in Visual Studio:

- In Tools -> Options -> VC++ Directories -> Include Files:

  > C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include
- In Configuration Properties → Linker → Additional Library
  Directories:

  > C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib

Comment: Wow, it's hard to get a good answer. I had problems because i didn't install the GForce drivers, and then the includes... You are clever man

Comment: You don't need GLUT. It's not a vital part required for developing with OpenGL. In fact I (personally) strongly disregard its use.

Comment: I know, but the question is how to set GLUT, openGL and Visual Studio 2008 specifically.

Answer (score 4):

MSDN has a [section on OpenGL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374278%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) that should help out, including sample code.